# What is the name of this ne waza?

Tags: judo, jujutsu, identification, submissions, groundwork

What is the name of this ne waza? https://youtu.be/VfI22dZ979A

[image: mystery technique]

Youtube transcript from commentator:

> The attacker drops down to a drop [knee] *seoi*. It fails, keeps pulling his opponent down. Once it going to *ne waza*, pulls
> down on the lapel, cross grips, pulls down,
> then catches the sleeve. Swings
> underneath him, tries to turn him over
> with his foot. That doesn't work, brings
> the foot behind the back and gets a coil
> lock on the opponent's right arm. Pushes
> the opponent's right arm with his foot
> in hand and now his left foot comes in,
> hooks by the elbow, catches by the top,
> near the head, starts to pull the
> opponent over on his back. Still has his
> right arm locked, swings over the top,
> comes across the neck, controlling with
> his left foot, brings the arm tight
> behind the back so he has two arm locks.
> Swings over the top, the opponent starts
> to give up. See, he's tapping just with his
> fingers; that's all he could move. Referee
> goes *osaekomi*, sees the hand, goes *ippon*.

Comment: I copied over the transcript contents and then fixed the errors as best I could, not being a *judo* person. My apologies for any errors, but I thought having some text would be useful.

Comment: Are you asking about a canonical judo name, or just a name?

Answer (score 4):

In the YouTube comments, [someone points out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfI22dZ979A&lc=UgwQHQqBJM23-IjBlTJ4AaABAg)

> Commenter "Gerijima" below says in japanese that the technique is called "itotoushi" (phonetically: ee-TOW TOW-oo-she) which in japanese means "thread pass through" as in the action of threading a needle. And he says this technique is in Shinya Aoki's book.

[Discussed a little further](https://www.reddit.com/r/judo/comments/w4le9/ito_toushi_thread_the_needle/) in the Judo Reddit forum, but no real new information added other than a bit of commentary on how it might have been escaped.

> All the guy on top had to do was swim his left hand to the inside, most likely isn't familiar with anything spider guard resembling and was expecting a quick stand up.

Answer (score 1):

In judo, this is called "Ude hishigi te gatame", or "Te gatame" for short, see [this video from Kodokan](https://youtu.be/6DnvhY0tQVM). Te gatame is an armlock, where you apply the technique solely with your hands (or arms), but without grapping your own wrist (then it be called "Ude garami").

Comment: Garami waza   name is used  for  about 90degrees angle  entanglement (Arm or Foot dosen't matter). te waza seem more like makura techinque

Comment: Ude-garami can also be applied to a straight arm, Ashi-garami in Katame-no-kata is indeed applied to the straight leg. A common mistake in many countries is that Garami always means an armlock applied to a bent arm.